# In pytest what is "quiet" mode, and what is the purpose?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am currently learning pytest and going through the documentation it is not clear what "quiet" mode is and what the reason for using it is. Can anyone clarify this to me?

In the documentation I see it is denoted with `-q` like such:

```
$ pytest -q test_sysexit.py
```

But what does this do?

Comment: As with many other software tools, "quiet" simply means "less output on the command line". Compare the [quiet](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html?highlight=quiet#asserting-that-a-certain-exception-is-raised) and [non-quiet](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html?highlight=quiet#our-first-test-run) examples on the getting started page.

Comment: I was looking at them, but the quiet example was showing a successful pass and the non quiet showed a non successful pass.  So was not sure if it really meant less output or if that was just because it passed it had nothing to tell me.

Comment: Try running the failing examples with the quiet flag and vice versa to see the difference.

Comment: I was planning on doing that later, but right now just reading documentation so wanted to see if I could get an answer before I started.  Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `-q` option will make pytest to be more concise in its output to the console.

There are more options similar to it:

- `-qq` will make pytest output even less information than `-q`.
- `-v` to output more information than the default amount.

Source: run `pytest --help` in shell:

```
    -v, --verbose         increase verbosity.
    -q, --quiet           decrease verbosity.
```